# How do you view the plots saved by the print() function in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

This is probably a simple question, but I have some files and data. After printing each one of them to a '-dpng' file, I just want to view the plot and copy them elsewhere. However, opening the file, all I see is the "Import Wizard". I click "Finish" and nothing happens. This is my code:

```
files = dir('*.csv');

for file = files'
   lab5 = csvread(file.name, 9)
   lab5(:,1) = log10(lab5(:,1))
   plot(lab5(:,1),lab5(:,2))
   print(strcat(file.name,'plot'), '-dpng')
end
```

I tried to avoid print() by using savefig, but for some reason savefig was giving me a vague error. Only print works, but I'm not sure how to view the output.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. It's saved as a picture in your current directory.

Comment: @excaza I just tried opening it through finder, but "there is no application set to open the document"

Comment: My problem is I can't see the plot. The file is saved there, but I cannot open it to view it.

Comment: Save it with a valid file extension or tell Finder to open it with Preview

Comment: @excaza Preview is grayed out when I choose an app to open it with. It should be saving as a valid extension because I specified what file to save it as

Comment: File *extension*, not filename. You're saving it as `'filename.csvplot'`.

Comment: @excaza Sorry, do you know the code for how I would remain it as a .png extension?

Comment: Concatenate the desired filename with `'.png'` and/or extract the filename from the extension with [`fileparts`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileparts.html)

Comment: Thank you! it works now. I had thought that print automatically added the extension

Comment: It does if you haven't specified one yourself, which you were. This is stated [in the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/print.html#description)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are saving your image as `filename.csvplot`, which Preview does not accept as a valid image file.

For example:

```
% Generate dummy file
fID = fopen('blah.csv', 'w');
fclose(fID);

% Recreate print job
files = dir('*.csv');
plot(1:10)
fname = strcat(files(1).name, 'plot');
print(fname, '-dpng');
```

Which gives us:

```
fname =

blah.csvplot
```

Why isn't `.png` appended to the filename? Per the documentation for [`print`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/print.html#description):

> If the file name does not include an extension, then `print` appends the appropriate one.

Filename inputs are parsed for an extension (e.g. things prepended with `.`), and does not append an extension if one is found. In this case, the filename passed to `print` has the `.csvplot` extension. This might be unexpected but it does make sense, file extensions don't actually control anything about the file itself; you could save your file as `image.finderpleaseopen` and have it still be a valid PNG file. Finder is just too stubborn to open it without being forced because it's not a known, supported file extension.

To fix this, you should save your file with the correct file extension. There are two ways to do this, append the correct extension or remove the undesired extension with something like [`fileparts`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileparts.html) or [`regexprep`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html) and let `print` handle it for you.

For example:

```
% blah.csvplot.png
fname = strcat(files(1).name, 'plot', '.png');
print(fname, '-dpng');

% blahplot.png
[~, filename] = fileparts(files(1).name);
fname = strcat(filename, 'plot');
print(fname, '-dpng');
```

---

[`savefig`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/savefig.html) does not produce a valid output for Finder because it does not produce any output without a `.fig` extension:

> If the specified file name does not include a `.fig` file extension, then MATLAB appends the extension. `savefig` does not accept other file extensions.

`*.fig` files are not image files and cannot be opened natively by finder.